# DiagramListener not being called?

Tags: javascript, gojs

I am trying to capture TreeExpanded and TreeCollapsed events, but the respective listeners are not being called. I have implemented the listeners as follows:

```
  myDiagram.addDiagramListener("TreeExpanded", function(e) {
    console.log(">>>>> STUFF HAPPENED in TreeExpanded");

  });

  myDiagram.addDiagramListener("TreeCollapsed", function(e) {
    console.log(">>>>> STUFF HAPPENED in TreeCollapsed");
  });
```

The full code for myDiagram looks like this:

```
  myDiagram = $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",
    {
      "undoManager.isEnabled": true,
      layout: $(go.TreeLayout),
      "ChangedSelection": onSelectionChanged
    });

  function geoFunc(geoname) {
    var geo = icons[geoname];
    if (geo === undefined) geo = icons["heart"];  // use this for an unknown icon name
    if (typeof geo === "string") {
      geo = icons[geoname] = go.Geometry.parse(geo, true);  // fill each geometry
    }
    return geo;
  }

  myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
    $(go.Node, "Auto",
      {isTreeExpanded:false},
      {doubleClick: function(e, node) {node.expandTree(1);}},
      $(go.Shape, "Rectangle",
        { strokeWidth: 2, stroke: colors["gray"],  },
        new go.Binding("fill", "color")),
      $(go.TextBlock, {stroke:"black",font:"12pt sans-serif",margin:3,wrap: go.TextBlock.WrapDesiredSize},new go.Binding("text", "geo"))


    );

  // Define a Link template that routes orthogonally, with no arrowhead
  myDiagram.linkTemplate =
    $(go.Link,
      { routing: go.Link.Orthogonal, corner: 5, toShortLength: -2, fromShortLength: -2 },
      $(go.Shape, { strokeWidth: 2, stroke: colors["gray"] })); // the link shape


  myDiagram.addDiagramListener("TreeExpanded", function(e) {
    console.log(">>>>> STUFF HAPPENED in TreeExpanded");

  });

  myDiagram.addDiagramListener("TreeCollapsed", function(e) {
    console.log(">>>>> STUFF HAPPENED in TreeCollapsed");
  });


  // Create the model data that will be represented by Nodes and Links
  myDiagram.model = new go.GraphLinksModel(
    [
```

How do I detect when a node tree is expanded or collapsed, then call a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling **Node.collapseTree** or **Node.expandTree** is a relatively low-level operation.  Your **doubleClick** event handler doesn't conduct a transaction (but any change should) nor does it raise any events such as "TreeExpanded" **DiagramEvent**.

Instead call, **CommandHandler.expandTree** or **CommandHandler.collapseTree**.  E.g.:

```
  {
    doubleClick: function(e, node) {
      e.diagram.commandHandler.expandTree(node); 
    }
  },
```

Comment: I don't understand. Does "e.diagram.commandHandler.expandTree();" cause the node tree to expand? I just want a function of my own design to be called when a node tree is collapsed or expanded. I do NOT want to manually expand or collapse nodes programatically. My question has nothing to do with responding to doubleClick events.I want to know WHEN a node is collapsed or expanded THEN call a function.

Comment: Only the commands raise the **DiagramEvent**s that you were trying to receive. If the **doubleClick** event handler was supposed to collapse a subtree, you need to both conduct a transaction and raise the **DiagramEvent**. I think you want to use **Node.treeExpandedChanged** event handler instead of the **DiagramEvent**s.

Comment: ignore the doubleclick event please, not relevant to this question. I would just like to listen for a TreeCollapsed / TreeExpanded event (that could be triggered by whatever) and have a function called when that happens.

Comment: Or do you mean the doubleclick event will not cause the TreeExpanded / TreeCollapsed events to fire?

Comment: Try https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Node.html#treeExpandedChanged instead of the DiagramEvents. The commands conduct a transaction and raise an event, as well as call the appropriate Node method and perform an animation.

Comment: Sorry lol, that took me a second to understand what you meant. Implementing your solution fixed my problem and now the TreeExpanded / Collapsed methods are being called! Thank you!

Comment: The **Node.treeExpandedChanged** event handler is called for each Node that changes state. The **DiagramEvent** listener is called only once per **CommandHandler** command.